# get resulting verticies from a gltransformation?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have some verticies and then I apply a glrotate(). I'd want to now what my verticies became after this transformation. How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918008/getting-values-of-an-object-after-a-call-to-rotatef-c)

You can't do that. There is a feedback buffer, but that's not what you are looking for.
Read my [previous explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918008/getting-values-of-an-object-after-a-call-to-rotatef-c/2918140#2918140) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any other way other than calling `glGet` with `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` and doing the resulting transform yourself. (Or calculating the same transformation matrix yourself, and apply it to your point.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but you probably don't want to go there. There is the so-called [transform feedback](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/transform_feedback.txt) which stores processed vertices in buffer objects. You can read back these and get your vertices. This might be useful if you have a *huge* amount of vertices, but my bet is that you're better of transforming the vertices on your own, as Thanatos proposed.

Comment: Alright, thanks (gets out scientific calculator and pushes sin and cos buttons)